# How to calculate the number of disk in RAID 1,5,10

Tags: raid

What is the formula for working out the total number of disks in RAID 1,5,10 array knowing the final RAID size/capacity?
I would really appreciate your response
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**RAID 1:** Impossible to calculate, because adding drives to RAID 1 doesn't increase the capacity.

**RAID 5:** If you have `n` drives of capacity `c`, then the array will have the total capacity `T` of:

```
T = (n-1) * c
```

With basic mathematical transformations you can solve for `n`:

```
T = (n-1) * c        | divide by c
T/c = n-1            | add 1
T/c + 1 = n          | swap sides for clarity
n = T/c + 1
```

**RAID 10:** Twice as much disks as without RAID, ie.

```
n = T/c * 2
```

because each pair of drives gives you half of their raw capacity.

Comment: thanks alot for your quick answer and Response I really appreciate